# In PHP/MYSQL daily transactions should start with three zeros

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I need your help in maintaining transactions daily that start with three zeros followed by some numbers (Example: 2015***000) and it has to increment for next transaction (Example: 2015***001, 2015***002) and so on.
Please help me how to handle transactions that should start with three zeros for first transaction of the day and increment further as shown in the first example...

Thanks
SURYAPRAKASH

Comment: Have you tried anything yet..?? please give some code you already worked on, then only people can help you here...

Comment: Sir, i haven't started coding for maintaining transaction ids. Hope u understood my query. Every day first transaction should start with 2015date000 and get incremented for another transaction and so on.... Please help me sir....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be help you

```
$transactionid = date('Y').date('d').'000';

$gettransid = mysql_query("select * from daily_transaction_tbl order by transaction_id desc");
$fetchtrans = mysql_fetch_array($gettransid);
$transfetchdid = $fetchtrans['transaction_id']+1;

// second time if u insert the query you need to use this 
if($transfetchdid == ""){
$inserttrans = mysql_query("insert into daily_transaction_tbl transaction_id values ($transactionid)");
}else{
$inserttrans = mysql_query("insert into daily_transaction_tbl transaction_id values ($transfetchdid)");
}
```

Comment: Sir the php variable $transactionid is just storing integers like 1 ,2and so on instead of 201503001, 201503002... Please clear my doubt

Comment: <?php include("db.php"); ?> <?php
$transactionid=date('Ymd').'000';
echo $transactionid;
$gettransid=mysql_query("select * from students_books order by transid desc")or die(mysql_error());
$fetchtrans=mysql_fetch_array($gettransid);
$transfetchdid=$fetchtrans['transid']+1;
//second time if you insert the query you need to use this
if($transfetchdid == ""){
 $inserttrans=mysql_query("insert into students_books (transid) values ('$transactionid')")or die(mysql_error());
}
else
{
 $inserttrans=mysql_query("insert into students_books (transid) values ('$transfetchdid')")or die(mysql_error());
}?>